# How to see the spark-launcher command being submitted when using org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher?

Tags: java, apache-spark, command, command-line-interface

Is there a way to see the spark-launcher CLI command that will be submitted to spark when using the following line in JAVA to send an already configured spark launcher?

```
SparkLauncher().launch();
```

---

Edit: The method "createBuilder" within "SparkLauncher.class" seems to have it, as a list, during the ".launch()" process.
Now this is a matter of finding the way to extract that information from the point there the "SparkLauncher().launch()" is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Given you define your sparkLauncher as: "launcher"
You can get the spark-submit command this way:

```
String sparkSubmitCommand = StringUtils.join(launcher.createBuilder().command(), " ");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `createBuilder` is private, at least in 2.4.0.